# Can Kubernetes prioritize nodes when scaling?

Tags: kubernetes, scaling

I have a Kubernetes cluster on AWS set up with KubeAWS. We're using some sensitive third-party integrations that require white-listed IP addresses in their firewall.

Now, what I've done is that I've registered the IP addresses of the nodes with the external services and added a node label (`whitelisted-ip=true`) to those nodes. Services that need to contact those third party providers then have this set as a `nodeSelector`. So far so good.

Now, the problem I run into is when the cluster starts scaling, in particular, when it's scaling down. The cluster doesn't seem to care which node it removes, so If I have two nodes in one availability zone, it might as well remove the one which has the white-listed IP, which is then released.

Can I instruct my cluster to, when scaling down, first remove nodes that don't have the node label `whitelisted-ip=true`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that I never shared the answer to this question.

As per [this post](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kube-aws/issues/1432#issuecomment-413507665), there's an annotation to solve this problem:

```
$ kubectl annotate node <nodename> cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/scale-down-disabled=true
```

This will prevent Kubernetes from scaling down the node in question.